# Sails.js pipeline file changes, sails lift the changes have not effect

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, sails.js, bower

I have a sails.js project, I have changed the array of `jsFilesToInject` and `cssFilesToInject` in `pipeline.js`, and run `grunt clean` and remove the `.tmp` folder then run `sails lift`. The changes are not made when I view source of the html file. It seems the changed js files and css files are not injected into the layout.ejs, and it still have previous files in it.

Comment: check the `layout.ejs` file. It should be updated automatically (after `sails lift`, of course ) if you changed the order of js and css files to be loaded in `pipeline.js`

Comment: @MjZac I have checked layout.ejs, it is not updating automatically.

Comment: then you might have some wrong entry in pipeline.js